# Python - How to Accept and Loop Over Multiple Files? Using agrv

Tags: python, file, loops, argv

I'm trying to create a program that will take multiple files and display the information below individually for each file.

```
#a)    The name of the file
#b)    The total number of words in the file, 
#c)    The first word in the file and the length
```

For example, if add two files on the command line: **test.txt** and **sample.txt** => the output will be 3 lines with the info(a-c) for file test.txt and 3 lines(a-c) for sample.txt.

**What I don't know is:**
- How to accept 1 or more files in the command line using argv? 
- How to loop over those files so open, read and display the output individually for each file?

I have a preliminary example below, but it can only take 1 file at a time. It's based on what I found in Learn Python the Hard Way.

```
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv

print "YOUR FILE NAME IS: %r" % (filename) 

step1 = open(filename)  
step2 = step1.read() 
step3 = step2.split() 
step4 = len(step3) 

print 'THE TOTAL NUMBER OF WORDS IN THE FILE: %d' % step4 

find1 = open(filename) 
find2 = find1.read() 
find3 = find2.split()[1]
find4 = len(find3) 

print 'THE FIRST WORD AND THE LENGTH: %s %d'  % (find3 , find4)
```

Comment: `script, filenames = argv[0], argv[1:]` may do what you want.

Comment: If you're looking how to loop and use the `for` statement though, you may want to read some more Python tutorials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this. Hopefully this can give you a general idea of how to approach the problem.

```
from sys import argv

script, filenames = argv[0], argv[1:]

# looping through files
for file in filenames:
    print('You opened file: {0}'.format(file))
    with open(file) as f:
        words = [line.split() for line in f] # create a list of the words in the file
        # note the above line will create a list of list since only one line exists,
        # you can edit/change accordingly
        print('There are {0} words'.format(len(words[0]))) # obtain length of list
        print('The first word is "{0}" and it is of length "{1}"'.format(words[0][0], 
                                                                         len(words[0][0])))
        # the above line provides the information, the first [0] is for the first 
        # set in the list (loop for multiple lines), the second [0] extract the first word
    print('*******-------*******')
```

Just be cautious that this works for a single line file with multiple words. If you have multiple lines, pay attention to the comments included in the script.

Comment: Thank you! this helped me understand what I had missing from my code. I made some modifications and now it working.